# Is there a RJ45 with magnetics for PHY less network switch

Tags: ethernet, network, rj45, isolated

I have a network switch indoor and camera outdoor. I plan on having a PCB with RJ45 with magnetics. Can any tell me how to choose an RJ45 with transformer for a PHY Less network switch.

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "RJ45 with magnetics". Can you explain that? RJ45 is a type of network interface.

Comment: Its RJ45 that has a transformer on it. Here is the link: https://www.digikey.com/products/en?mpart=0826-1X1T-HT-F&v=507

Comment: If you intend to use an RJ45 with magnetics you CANNOT use a PHY-less port. If you intend to use a PHY-Less port then you have to use a chip that supports this direct serial connection. Notice that you switch has multiple PHY based ports and 1* 10Gbe PHY-less port …..I don't think you want to connect your camera through that.

Comment: i think that you need to use an SFP transceiver

Comment: @KingDuken RJ45 is just a connector, it's not a "network interface" until you add circuitry around it.

Comment: what sort of "isolate" are you going for?

Comment: RJ45 have transformer that have an isolation rating  of 6KV or 2KV. That is what I am going for.

Comment: The network switch doesn't consist of transformer. Therefore, I want to add a transformer on a PCB. I have found that RJ45 comes with transformer. The circuitry, will consist of current limiting resistor, and a tvs diode. For now, what I want to know is how do I choose a transformer for a Network Switch (PHY chip)